# Asterisk: Can call and answer but no voice or video

Tags: asterisk, sip

I set up a simple asterisk server on a debian server.
My goal is to make two android phones call each other, using voice and later video, on my asterisk server.   Actually they are connected via 3G/4G network, and I use imsDroid softphone.

**I can make both phones call each other, I can answer the call on both ends.
But I can't hear anything nor see any video.**
I'm a beginner using SIP protocol and asterisk. I may have configured asterisk or the softphones badly.

**Do you know how to resolve this issue ? Or even how to debug it ?**  Thanks!

sip.conf:

```
[general]
context=internal
allowguest=no
allowoverlap=no
bindport=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
srvlookup=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
alwaysauthreject=yes
canreinvite=no
nat=yes
session-timers=refuse
localnet=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0


[7001]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=123
context=internal

[7002]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=456
context=internal
```

extensions.conf:

```
[internal]
exten => 7001,1,Answer()
exten => 7001,2,Dial(SIP/7001,60)
exten => 7001,3,Playback(vm-nobodyavail)
exten => 7001,4,VoiceMail(7001@main)
exten => 7001,5,Hangup()

exten => 7002,1,Answer()
exten => 7002,2,Dial(SIP/7002,60)
exten => 7002,3,Playback(vm-nobodyavail)
exten => 7002,4,VoiceMail(7002@main)
exten => 7002,5,Hangup()

exten => 8001,1,VoicemailMain(7001@main)
exten => 8001,2,Hangup()

exten => 8002,1,VoicemailMain(7002@main)
exten => 8002,2,Hangup()
```

modules.conf:

```
[modules]
autoload=no
load=pbx_config.so
load=chan_sip.so
load=chan_iax2.so
load=res_rtp_asterisk.so
load=app_hangup.so
load=app_dial.so
load=codec_ulaw.so
load=codec_gsm.so
```

Comment: This question really is off-topic here, as you're essentially asking for advice on configuration and/or networking. First off -- is your asterisk server on a public IP? It can not be behind NAT.

Comment: The server obviously have a public ip (the one that softphones use), but indeed it's behind a NAT...

Comment: Which one is it? Public or behind NAT? You can't have both. Do you mean NAT with port-forwarding? If so, you need to configure your media-ports as well or set up STUN.

Comment: I'm fairly new to networking also, as you guessed. I think it's a NAT with port-forwarding. I tried to set up numb.viagenie.ca STUN server on the softphones, but when I use it, I can't even receive a call !

Comment: Asterisk with port-forwarding is difficult at best. Better put it in the DMZ if your router has that option... or forward the media ports. Good luck!

Comment: I am facing same issue. I am able to call but no voice during calling.. same this is working while I am in my office wifi.. I have already set Nat = yes , externip and localnet with qualify = yes ..even I have added 5060 UDP port and 10000-20000 UDP port.. and forwarded to my local machine where asterisk is installed.. can any one suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved !
I had to configure `externip=my.external.ip` in `sip.conf`, because I'm running asterisk behind a NAT !
I also added `h263 codec` to make video work, and added `videosupport=yes` in `sip.conf`